# Default value data type does not match data type for column DATES_DATE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to make a table in Snowflake but it is giving me error due to default value. This seems to work fine in Oracle but not Snowflake.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
DATES_DATE TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

Error-
`SQL compilation error: Default value data type does not match data type for column DATES_DATE` 
Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: How does it feel about timestamp literals - `DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` ?

Comment: @AlexPoole It is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE A(
DATES_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

Or

```
CREATE or replace TABLE A(
DATES_DATE TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with - TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::TIMESTAMP(3) since I wanted to define (3)

Answer (score 1):

Using `'1900-01-01'::TIMESTAMP(3)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE A(
   DATES_DATE TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '1900-01-01'::TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```